# Why won't the game detect my Xbox 360 controller anymore?

Tags: pc, super-street-fighter-iv

SSFIV:AE suddenly decided to stop detecting my Xbox 360 controller, while it's always been working out of the box.
What I tried, so far:

- restart Steam
- update Steam
- verify the integrity of game cache (via the game's properties, "local files" tab)
- uninstall the game (by removing local game files) and install it again
- unplug/replug the controller

Any idea ?

Comment: Remove it while the game is closed, restart PC,plug it back and try again?

Comment: Basically what @Assylum said, I've had this problem before and I just close steam, unplug then plug back in the controller and load steam back up and it should recognise it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so rebooting Windows did the trick.  That being, I have no idea how or why it suddenly stopped to work, nor why rebooting Windows fixed the issue.

Comment: Sometimes Errrors like this just happen.. maybe the device crashed or the USB Port Driver had an issue. You never know. A restart is the first thing to do when you got any hardware issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that alt+tab actually works wonders for SFIV PC. Not only does it force it to re-detect my controller, but it also cures the repeat problem when playing from a keyboard.

Edit: To be specific, I'm using a hitbox controller on Ultra Street Fighter IV. I have it connected via a passive USB hub.

Comment: Yep, I ended up with the same solution.  Really annoying, but does the trick.